# Datastage 8.1 Change temporary directories for SORT operations

Tags: datastage

Someone knows how to change temporary directory location from Datastage configuration? My problems is while a SORT operation is performed, unix directories /var and /tmp are filled over its limit and whole process is failing.

I tried change **dsenv** and **uvconfig** under DSEngine directory, adding variables **TMP, TMPDIR and TEMPDIR** pointing to other directories then restart DS services,but is not working /tmp and /var still filled to 100% showing this error:

> Sort,0: sort: 0653-657 A write error occurred while sorting.
>
> Sort,0: Failure during execution of operator logic.
>
> Sort,0: Fatal Error: Null arg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sort area is specified in the config file specified in APT_CONFIG_FILE.
So check if the job uses a special one - in this case the APT_CONFIG_FILE would have to be a job parameter. If not the default one for the project is used - check it out in the Administor.

For details how to configure it see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/c_deeref_Configuration_Files_parallel_engine_config_file.html)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelTiefenbacher